# Does CALayer support vector art or does it only handle pre-rendered raster art?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer, resolution, vector-graphics

I think the answer is no, but asking anyway.
Does CALayer support vector art?

I get the sense there is some resolution dependence on the resolution of the image used for a CALayer. 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does, in the sense that a layer subclass, or delegate of a layer can be asked to draw on-demand by the layer. You can fairly easily draw vector art into the layer this way.

Comment: Interesting point. Now I need to locate some sample code to see this in action. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for vector images in QuartzCore.

It means that there are no in-built API's to read and draw any of the vector image formats.

It's possible to write code to read and parse svg format (which is essentially and XML file) and draw everything using primitive drawing methods (creating paths and stroking them)... but that means you have to do everything from scratch yourself.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Done. Let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Turns out though you can draw in drawLayer

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Sure the docs say as much. You can use drawLayer to draw into the layer. How to animate that I don't know yet.